# Does Karate DSL Framework has the capability of performing load testing

Tags: karate

Currently, we've automated all of our web services using the Karate framework and it is super cool.Is there any way we can do the load testing with this tool? 
Example: Given when I enroll a member 1000 times
         Then the average response time should be 2.7 milliseconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the developer of Karate and it is great to hear this feedback, thanks !

Karate was not designed for load-testing - but we would like to support it in the future. But it is not a priority now, and there are things like mocking we want to get to sooner which we feel is a more critical need for many teams.

If you or the community would be willing to investigate and contribute, that would be great. One experiment I can think of is using the [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) try to create multiple threads and run a `*.feature` file.

EDIT: Karate now has Gatling integration: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-gatling-demo

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday as part of my POC work w.r.t API demonstrated Karate in my office people were very much impressed. thanks for Karate team.

Comment: Happy to hear how impressed people were with you. Would you mind sharing your knowledge with the op so he gets more out of this than "Yes."? E.g. you could elaborate on the example he gave.