# How to trigger the same request more than once parallel at same time in karate DSL

Tags: karate

I have encountered a scenario where I need to trigger the same request multiple times to check that there have not been multiple updates in the DB.

-> I need to try with the same user login and triggering the request multiple times, as well as different users, try to trigger the same request at same time.

Comment: you can perform load testing. please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350533/does-karate-dsl-framework-has-the-capability-of-performing-load-testing) . or use [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196077/integration-karate-feature-file-with-jmeter-for-load-testing?noredirect=1&lq=1)